How to bind a pick event callback directly to an artisti in matplotlib
I'm drawing 2 lines into a figure and I want to draw a vertical line when clicking the lines.
What I want is the callback "on_pick_line1" being called when clicking on line "y1" and "on_pick_line2" when clicking on line y2.
All examples in the documentation show how to bind a callback to the event "on_pick" of the canvas but it does not know which line has been clicked.
I wrote the Pick_dispatcher class that routes the "on_pick" events to my callbacks. The solution works but, in my opinion is complicated.
Is there any way to bind the callback "on_pick_line1" directly to line "y1" and so on?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Pick_dispatcher():
    """Pick callbacks register themselfs into the dispatcher, then they'll get called"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = {}

    def register_callback(self, artist, func):
        self.callbacks[artist] = func

    def unregister_callback(self, artist, func):
        del self.callbacks[artist]

    def __call__(self, event):
        artist = event.artist
        print("Dispatcher calling ", artist.get_label())
        self.callbacks[artist](event)



def on_pick_line1(event):
    artist = event.artist
    i_sel = event.ind                       # list of indexes selected vertices
    i_med = i_sel[len(i_sel) // 2]          # index of median vertex
    x = artist.get_xdata()[i_med]           # median vertex
    ax = artist.axes
    ax.axvline(x, ls='--', lw=1, color='blue')
    artist.get_figure().canvas.draw_idle()



def on_pick_line2(event):
    artist = event.artist
    i_sel = event.ind
    i_med = i_sel[len(i_sel) // 2]
    x = artist.get_xdata()[i_med]
    ax = artist.axes
    ax.axvline(x, ls='--', lw=1, color='red')
    artist.get_figure().canvas.draw_idle()




if __name__ == "__main__":


    # Sample traces
    x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
    y1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6])
    y2 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])

    # Prepare plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    pick_dispatcher = Pick_dispatcher()

    tolerance = 5 # points
    f, = ax.plot(x, y1, marker=".", ms=2, lw=1, label='y1', picker=True, pickradius=tolerance)
    pick_dispatcher.register_callback(f, on_pick_line1)

    g, = ax.plot(x, y2, marker=".", ms=2, lw=1, label='y2', picker=True, pickradius=tolerance)
    pick_dispatcher.register_callback(g, on_pick_line2)

    plt.legend()

    fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', pick_dispatcher)
    plt.show()


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_pick_line1(event):
    artist = event.artist
    i_sel = event.ind                       # list of indexes selected vertices
    i_med = i_sel[len(i_sel) // 2]          # index of median vertex
    x = artist.get_xdata()[i_med]           # median vertex
    ax = artist.axes
    ax.axvline(x, ls='--', lw=1, color='blue')
    artist.get_figure().canvas.draw_idle()

def on_pick_line2(event):
    artist = event.artist
    i_sel = event.ind
    i_med = i_sel[len(i_sel) // 2]
    x = artist.get_xdata()[i_med]
    ax = artist.axes
    ax.axvline(x, ls='--', lw=1, color='red')
    artist.get_figure().canvas.draw_idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Sample traces
    x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
    y1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6])
    y2 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])

    # Prepare plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    tolerance = 5  # points
    line1, = ax.plot(x, y1, marker=".", ms=2, lw=1, label='y1', picker=True, pickradius=tolerance)
    line2, = ax.plot(x, y2, marker=".", ms=2, lw=1, label='y2', picker=True, pickradius=tolerance)

    # Bind callbacks directly
    def on_pick(event):
        if event.artist == line1:
            on_pick_line1(event)
        elif event.artist == line2:
            on_pick_line2(event)

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


You can simplify the process of binding callbacks directly to lines in Matplotlib without needing a custom dispatcher by using the picker attribute of the artists and handling the pick event more directly. This approach avoids creating an intermediary class and routes callbacks based on the artist that was picked.

Thank you for your answer. The solution is somewhat similar to my implementation, it uses a function instead of a class, but the concept is the same: an intermediate layer that routes the event object. The documentation says that i can pass a callabel to artist.set_picker() but in that case I have to determine if the artist is hit by the mouse and I have no idea how to do it.
